# Ubunto 16.10 no internet on Windows 10 Hyper-V

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hyper-v

I have hyper-v installed on my workstation and am trying to install Ubuntu on a new VM. So far I have been unable to get internet connectivity.

[image: Wired Ethernet connection appears to be unplugged.]

I have tried the following:

1. Using an External Switch: I think it should work this way.
2. Sharing Internet between Internal / External Switch: Setup a internal and external network switches and then share the internet connectivity from the external switch with the internal switch.
3. Setting up a bridge: Setup an internal switch and then create a bridge between my Ethernet adapter and the internal switch.

**ONE. Using an External Switch**

This is how I would expect it to work out of the box without any hacking around. But it doesn't.

**TWO. Sharing Internet between Internal / External Switch**

This has no effect on the internet connectivity of the Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

**THREE. Setting up a bridge**

This results in internet not working on neither the guest OS nor the host OS.

Comment: Having similar issues and beginning to wonder if it's because I'm running Windows 10 Inside preview and something is wrong with Hyper-V functionality in Windows 10 Insider builds. Typing winver from console I see my Windows 10 version is: Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.14). What Windows version are you running?